# Best way to make only one way i.e activity to service communication?

Tags: android, service

one way communication from activity to service and the service runs indefinitely until the activity commands it to stop.

Comment: see `Context#startService()`

Comment: could you please explain?

Comment: what is unclear after reading `startService()` javadocs?

Comment: how to establish IPC in starter service

Comment: I have no idea what you mean

Answer (score 0):

You can use broadcast receiver for communicating between service and activity

Your Service should be like this :-

```
public class MyService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "com.example.ServiceExample";

@Override
  public void onCreate() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    //SendBroadCast to Activity
   Intent intent = new Intent("my-event");
   intent.putExtra("message", "data");
   sendBroadcast(intent);
     return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind");
    return null;
}

@Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy");
}
 }
```

Your Activity should be like this :-

```
public class BindingActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

}

/** Called when a button is clicked (the button in the layout file attaches to
  * this method with the android:onClick attribute) */
public void onButtonClick(View v) {

}

   private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()       {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  // Extract data included in the Intent
  String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
  Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
 }
 };

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();

 // Register mMessageReceiver to receive messages.
 registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
  new IntentFilter("my-event"));
  }

@Override
 protected void onPause() {
    // Unregister since the activity is not visible
    unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
      super.onPause();
            } }

              }
```

Comment: Service is not designed for long running tasks? see also http://techtej.blogspot.hk/2011/03/android-thread-constructspart-4.html

Comment: @kracken this bounded service is not running indefinetly. what should i do?

Comment: Bound Service will run as longer as your Activity to which it is bounded is running.

Comment: If you want it to run indefinetly then you have to use Normal Android Service and need to register dynamic broadcast receiver in your activity, So that you can send broadcast from your service and get it in onReceive() of BroadcastReceiver of your Activity

Comment: But only one way communication is required from activity to service. I tried sending data using intent but it is not dynamic. and i have to start the service again and again